# Redis to store large lists

Tags: performance, data-structures, redis, in-memory-database

I'm quite new to Redis and I'm not sure if my use case is a good fit for Redis.

I need to store a list of users per company ID.

```
"companyA" : [
    {userName: xyz1, experience: 23,skills: [{name: python, score: 10}, ...], profilePicture:...},
    {userName: xyz2, experience: 23,skills:[{name: react, score: 10}, ...],  profilePicture:...},
    {userName: xyz3, experience: 23,skills:[{name: java, score: 10}, ...],  profilePicture:...},
    {userName: xyz4, experience: 23,skills:[{name: javascript, score: 10}, ...],  profilePicture:...},
  ]
```

Now I have a `scoringFunction(companyId, skills[])` that takes a `companyID` and a list of skills. This function will then retrieve all the users from Redis and calculate a score based on the given list of skills.

I was wondering if this is a relevant use case for Redis as the list of users per company can get relatively large. I have the feeling that parsing the objects in this array every time would consume a lot of memory...

My two questions:

- Should I use Redis and if so is storing the users as a list the way to go?
- Is there maybe a better alternative for this use case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can use list data type to store list of users id in a company

eg: `company:<id>` as key and `user:1`, `user:2`, .... as list item.

and then user meta goes to another key `user:<id>`, could be hash or string